# how to convert logback.xml file to log4j2.properties file?

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I am using logback with springboot. But now i need to migrate from logback to log4j2. I need to convert the follwing logback.xml into log4j2.properties. And what dependency should i need to add for log4j2. Please help me with this.

```
<property resource="application-logging.yml" />

<appender name = "STDOUT" class = "ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="INFO_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${fileName}/logfile.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${fileName}/logfile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<logger name="com.samplelogging.logging.filter" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="INFO_FILE" />
</logger>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Log4j2, you can use this dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also in the properties section of your pom.xml, you must specify the latest log4j2 version in which the vulnerability is fixed, i.e.

```
<properties>
    <log4j2.version>2.17.0</log4j2.version>
</properties>
```

And this is my log4j2.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %c:%L - %m%n
        </Property>
        <Property name="LOG_DIR">@log.dir@/@app.name@</Property>
        <Property name="APP_NAME">@app.name@</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="rollingFileLogger"
            fileName="${LOG_DIR}/${APP_NAME}.log"
            filePattern="${LOG_DIR}/${APP_NAME}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.myorg" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="rollingFileLogger" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The `@log.dir@` and `@app.name@` are the placeholders for actual values from my `application.properties` file.

To use log4j2.properties instead of log4j2.xml, sample :

```
status = warn
name= com.myorg

# Log files location
property.basePath = @log.dir@/@app.name@

# RollingFileAppender name, pattern, path and rollover policy
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = fileLogger
appender.rolling.fileName= "${basePath}/${APP_NAME}.log"
appender.rolling.filePattern= ${basePath}/app_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy

# Console appender configuration
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = consoleLogger
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Configure root logger
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger
```

Comment: You can use the [Spring Boot Lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#SpringLookup) to retrieve those `@log.dir@` and `@app.name@` values.

Comment: @Urvashi Soni: Thanks for the reply. Can you convert this log4j2.xml to log4j2.properties please?

Comment: @Susmitha I have edited my ans.

Comment: You are missing `appender.rolling.policies.type=Policies`. Alternatively you can replace the [`CompositeTriggeringPolicy`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/CompositeTriggeringPolicy.html) with a simple `TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy`: `appender.rolling.time.type=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy`.

Comment: @Susmitha If my ans is useful to you and correct as per your requirements, please mark it as Accepted ans.

Comment: Even though i am specifying `name= com.samplelogging.logging.filter` I am getting all the spring startup logs along with that. How to get logs specific to only that package or class?